# Is there an way to add a toggle to switch which values are being aggregated in a pivot table?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, aggregate, toggle

I am wondering if there is an easy way to add some sort of toggle or filter option that allows me to quickly change between the values I am looking to measure in a pivot table. Here is a really simple example:

[image]

You can see here that currently the pivot table is currently summing "Price". I want to have some sort of toggle that would allow me to quickly change the table from summing "Price", to summing "Count", so that it looks like this:

[image]

I recognize that I can just have both sums appear next to each other, and that would probably make the most sense in this simplified example, but in reality my pivot table is a lot more complex, and I'm looking for a way to change between aggregation Values easily (and without creating a new pivot table).

Comment: Why don't add both sums at same time? Also, you've tagged the question with VBA so please post the code you've tried to handle this

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I removed the tag - I hadn't tried any code but figured that could be implemented in a possible solution. And I want to be able to toggle because in reality, the pivot table I want to do this with has many more dimensions, and adding both would make it hard to read and understand.

Comment: Easy way for this would be having 2 Pivot Tables, 1 with sum and 1 with count. just switch the page and that would be like a toggle. Other way would be using VBA to toggle with a click, but you would need to code it or hire somebody, so consider if it's worth it